# Unknown Ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery ajax code is like this

```
 $(".head-text").live('click', function (event) {

        var url = new URI().addQuery("showlist", 1);
        $.ajax({
            url: url, type: "GET"
            , success: function (data) {

                var $response = $(data);
                alert($response.html);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

and the alert always displays this message

```
 function ( str ) {
    if ( typeof str != 'undefined' )
    {
      if ( this.data( 'dotdotdot' ) )
      {
        if ( typeof str != 'function' )
        {
          return this.trigger( 'update', [ str ] );
        }
      }
      return _orgHtml.call( this, str );
    }
    return _orgHtml.call( this );
    }
```

I cant understand what went wrong or what this means.I just want to see the result html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `()`. So you get the source code of the `.html()` method.

```
alert( $response.html() );
```